# Find the interior product of a basic p-form $\alpha = dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_p$ and a vector field $X$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-forms, smooth-manifolds

I'm reading Differentiable Manifolds by Nigel Hitchin, that is, his class notes for an Oxford course freely available [here](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/hitchin/hitchinnotes/manifolds2012.pdf). In particular, I'm trying to understand the interior product on manifolds, and how he works out his example.

So the example given is of a basic p-form $\alpha = dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_p$ and a vector field $X = \sum_{i}a_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$. It is then stated that the interior product is given by $$i_{X}\alpha = a_1 dx_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_p - a_2dx_1 \wedge dx_3 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_p + \ldots$$

Can anyone help me understand how one comes to this conclusion? In the proposition prior to the example, given a vector field $X$ on a manifold $M$, the interior product is characterized as a linear map $i_X: \Omega^p(M) \to \Omega^{p-1}(M)$ s.t. $i_Xdf = X(f)$ and $i_X(\alpha \wedge \beta) = i_X \alpha \wedge \beta + (-1)^p \alpha \wedge i_X \beta$ for $\alpha \in \Omega^p(M)$.

Based on this definition I was looking to find a $p-1$-form $\beta$ such that $$X(\beta) = a_1 dx_2 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_p - a_2dx_1 \wedge dx_3 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_p + \ldots,$$ so kind of an "antiderivative".

To me it looks like $$\beta = x_1 dx_2 \wedge dx_3 \wedge \ldots dx_p + x_2 dx_1 \wedge dx_3 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_p + \ldots + x_p dx_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_{p-1}$$

would work, but then $d \beta = p dx_1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx_p = p \alpha$, isn't it? So if that was my $\beta$, then I wouldn't get the connection between $df$ and $f$ in the first property of $i_X$.

Anyway, help here would be greatly appreciated, since I really can't seem to wrap my head around this one.

edit: OK, so I've been struggling with this for hours, but minutes after posting I think I'm starting to get it. I think that in order to obtain the expression I can just split $\alpha = \alpha_0 \wedge \alpha_1$, where $\alpha_0 = dx_1$ and $\alpha_1 = dx_2 \wedge \ldots dx_p$. Then I can apply the second property of $i_X$ along with the fact that $i_X(dx_j) = X(x_j) = a_j$. Proceeding inductively I would indeed then get the desired result. Is this the correct way of going about it? Or is there an easier and more straightforward way of doing it?

Comment: The approach you outline in your edit is the correct one.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese, thanks. So I'm guessing the first property is only true for functions $f$ then, right? That is, we don't have $i_X d \alpha = X(\alpha)$ when $\alpha$ is a $p$-form for $p > 1$. Because I guess this is what was throwing me off, as I was assuming that property *did* hold for any $p$-form.

Comment: @Ryker : Yes, it holds only for functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments, the approach you mention in your edit is the correct one.

Using the property $i_X(\alpha\wedge\beta) = (i_X\alpha)\wedge\beta + (-1)^p\alpha\wedge(i_X\beta)$, computing $i_X(dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^p)$ reduces to computing $i_X(dx^j)$ which can be evaluated as follows:

$$i_X(dx^j) = dx^j(X) = X(x^j) = \sum_ia_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(x_j) = \sum_ia_i\frac{\partial x_j}{\partial x_i} = \sum_i a_i\delta_{ij} = a_j.$$

Alternatively,

$$i_X(dx^j) = dx^j(X) = dx^j\left(\sum_ia_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right) = \sum_ia_idx^j\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\right) = \sum_ia_i\delta_{ij} = a_j.$$